# Get multiple AND single types for doctrine Entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity

I have an Entity that is basically :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="HebergementType", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hebergement_type", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="HebergementType", inversedBy="hebergements", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="hebergement_hebergementtype",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="hebergement_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="hebergementtype_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $mType;
```

This creates the following **tables** :

- **hebergement**

  - With: id, hebergement_type
- **hebergement_hebergementtype**

  - With: hebergement_id, hebergementtype_id
- **hebergement_type**

  - With: id

But now I have some info in **hebergement_hebergementtype** (multiple type support) and some info in **hebergement.hebergement_type** (single type support).

How can I get all **hebergement_type**s that are '**populated**' by using JOIN hebergement with hebergement_type and hebergement."mType" (multiple type, uses hebergement_hebergementtype) ?

Answer (score 0):

If your relations have properties, that is a sign, that it is not simply a relation, but an Entity itself.

**hebergement_hebergementtype** could simply be an Entity like **HebergementTypeAssignment** with relations to other entities.